# How do I get the Document object from a separate URL?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I'm making a program to parse a bunch of information from several pages of a database website for a JavaScript library. Just by messing around with the console, I've figured out how to isolate the information I need, but I don't know how to access the information from the parsing program. I'm almost exclusively proficient at HTML/JavaScript, so naturally I'm sticking with what I know for what should be a relatively simple parser. Here's the basic idea of what I intend to do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var outsideHTML = getDocumentByURL("https://www.example-database.com/page-"+i);

    //other code that parses information from the variable "outsideHTML"
}
```

I just need a function to serve as `getDocumentByURL()`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can get the html using ajax call and either host it to a iframe and access it that way..

Comment: If you use an `<iframe>` its `iframeElement.contentWindow.document`, but you have to have CORS access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to something called [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), you cannot access the document or other contents of another webpage using client-side JavaScript unless the other webpage is on the same domain as your webpage, or unless the other website explicitly allows it by supporting [JSONP](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp) or [setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin). It sounds like you're trying to retrieve a webpage, so JSONP isn't relevant, and it's fairly uncommon for Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers to be set on a webpage. Thus, this probably isn't possible to accomplish in the way you've described.

To retrieve the data from the other website, there's a couple approaches you can take:

1. Run server-side code (i.e. PHP, Node.js, Java, etc) that retrieves the other webpage and extracts the information you need. Server-side code is not affected by browser security policies such as same origin policy.
2. Use a cross-origin proxy (such as [crossorigin.me](https://crossorigin.me/)). This proxy will retrieve the data for you and add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers that allow you to access the page contents.
3. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you might transform your idea from a webpage to a browser extension -- browser extensions can be given the freedom to ignore same-origin policy.
4. Ask the website owner if they'd be willing to accommodate you by providing the data in a friendlier format.

Note that both of the first two approaches result in the request being made from a server rather than from the client's computer. This means that you can't retrieve any information that requires that they be logged into the website.